# Getting an .ics file to add an event on Google calendar

Tags: google-calendar, ics

I am trying to create an .ics file that will be placed on a web page.

People who click the link will download the .ics file to automatically add the event to their calendar.

Is there any way to make this work with Google Calendar as well?

Comment: The visitor can import the .ics file via your site's URL... This has been a function for a very long time... The problem I've experienced, however, is that sometimes, if you update your .ics calendar, Google doesn't always fetch the changes which then causes the imported calendar to become not up to date...

Comment: This isn't the impression I am going for. I want to enable someone to add a single pre-schedule event - the information of a webinar one registers to - by pressing a link on a web page (not inside an email). I want the effort on the side of the user to be as limited as fathomly possible

Comment: If you simply upload your .ics file to your website then visitors can copy the .ics file URL (from your website) and go to Google calendar and import your calendar events...

Comment: Too many steps. I want them to press a link that would open a new item in their Google Calendar